# Erlang install troubles

Tags: macos, gcc, erlang, homebrew

I need to be able to use Erlang for some university stuff. I tried all the ways to do it described [here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.2.1/tutorials/installation/Installing-Erlang/#Installing-on-Mac-OS-X):

- Using MacPorts
- Using Homebrew
- Using command line

When I used command line I also tried adding *sudo* in front of the commands, but I was still getting the same error:

```
Ignoring the --cache-file argument since it can cause the system to be erroneously configured
Disabling caching
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking for gcc... gcc-4.2
checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

The config.log file looks like this:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.59.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --disable-hipe --enable-smp-support --enable-threads --enable-kernel-poll --enable-darwin-64bit

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Andreys-MacBook-Air.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 13.0.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
hostinfo               = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 214 tasks, 1264 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 2.09, Mach factor: 1.90
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /opt/X11/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1650: checking build system type
configure:1668: result: i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
configure:1676: checking host system type
configure:1690: result: i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
configure:1779: checking for gcc
configure:1805: result: gcc-4.2
configure:2049: checking for C compiler version
configure:2052: gcc-4.2 --version </dev/null >&5
./configure: line 2053: gcc-4.2: command not found
configure:2055: $? = 127
configure:2057: gcc-4.2 -v </dev/null >&5
./configure: line 2058: gcc-4.2: command not found
configure:2060: $? = 127
configure:2062: gcc-4.2 -V </dev/null >&5
./configure: line 2063: gcc-4.2: command not found
configure:2065: $? = 127
configure:2088: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2091: gcc-4.2  -DNDEBUG  conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 2092: gcc-4.2: command not found
configure:2094: $? = 127
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2133: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
ac_cv_build_alias=i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
ac_cv_env_AR_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=gcc-4.2
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAG_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAG_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=-DNDEBUG
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_DED_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_DED_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_DED_LD_FLAG_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_DED_LD_FLAG_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_DED_LD_set=
ac_cv_env_DED_LD_value=
ac_cv_env_ERL_TOP_set=
ac_cv_env_ERL_TOP_value=
ac_cv_env_GETCONF_set=
ac_cv_env_GETCONF_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_value=
ac_cv_env_LFS_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LFS_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LFS_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LFS_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LFS_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LFS_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_value=
ac_cv_env_STATIC_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_STATIC_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_after_morecore_hook_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_after_morecore_hook_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_bigendian_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_bigendian_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_clock_gettime_cpu_time_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_clock_gettime_cpu_time_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_dlsym_brk_wrappers_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_dlsym_brk_wrappers_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_double_middle_endian_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_double_middle_endian_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_getaddrinfo_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_getaddrinfo_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_gethrvtime_procfs_ioctl_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_gethrvtime_procfs_ioctl_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_isysroot_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_isysroot_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_kqueue_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_kqueue_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_linux_clock_gettime_correction_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_linux_clock_gettime_correction_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_linux_nptl_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_linux_nptl_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_linux_usable_sigaltstack_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_linux_usable_sigaltstack_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_linux_usable_sigusrx_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_linux_usable_sigusrx_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_poll_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_poll_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_putenv_copy_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_putenv_copy_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_reliable_fpe_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_reliable_fpe_value=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_sysroot_set=
ac_cv_env_erl_xcomp_sysroot_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
ac_cv_host_alias=i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc-4.2

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
BOOTSTRAP_ONLY='no'
CC='gcc-4.2'
CFLAGS=''
CFLAG_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_PATH=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-DNDEBUG'
CROSS_COMPILING='no'
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DED_LD=''
DED_LDFLAGS=''
DED_LD_FLAG_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_PATH=''
DEFAULT_VERBOSITY=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C='ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
ERL_TOP='/Users/Novarg/Downloads/otp_src_R16B'
ERTS_VSN=''
EXEEXT=''
GETCONF=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LFS_CFLAGS=''
LFS_LDFLAGS=''
LFS_LIBS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKE_PROG=''
NATIVE_LIBS_ENABLED=''
OBJEXT=''
OTP_REL=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STATIC_CFLAGS=''
TARGET='i386-apple-darwin13.0.0'
ac_ct_CC='gcc-4.2'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_LD=''
ac_ct_RANLIB=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i386-apple-darwin13.0.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i386'
build_os='darwin13.0.0'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${prefix}/share'
erl_xcomp_after_morecore_hook=''
erl_xcomp_bigendian=''
erl_xcomp_clock_gettime_cpu_time=''
erl_xcomp_dlsym_brk_wrappers=''
erl_xcomp_double_middle_endian=''
erl_xcomp_getaddrinfo=''
erl_xcomp_gethrvtime_procfs_ioctl=''
erl_xcomp_isysroot=''
erl_xcomp_kqueue=''
erl_xcomp_linux_clock_gettime_correction=''
erl_xcomp_linux_nptl=''
erl_xcomp_linux_usable_sigaltstack=''
erl_xcomp_linux_usable_sigusrx=''
erl_xcomp_poll=''
erl_xcomp_putenv_copy=''
erl_xcomp_reliable_fpe=''
erl_xcomp_sysroot=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i386-apple-darwin13.0.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i386'
host_os='darwin13.0.0'
host_vendor='apple'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${prefix}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${prefix}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
subdirs=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""

configure: exit 77
```

When I used *Homebrew* it went all well(I think), but then it's stuck after

```
==> make install
```

and the terminal tab says **grep**. I can type in there, so it's not frozen. It just doesn't seem to do anything anymore.

What am I missing? How can I force it to work?

I'm using OS X 10.9(Mavericks)

Comment: Is it possible that you have set the `CC` environment variable to `gcc-4.2`?   From the `config.log` output, it seems like the configure script is picking up that name, and then failing because that compiler doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @legoscia yes, following that website I executed this command in command line: `CC=gcc-4.2 CPPFLAGS='-DNDEBUG' MAKEFLAGS='-j 3' ./configure --disable-hipe --enable-smp-support --enable-threads --enable-kernel-poll --enable-darwin-64bit`1

Comment: That will only work if you have a compiler called `gcc-4.2` in `PATH`.

Comment: @legoscia thanks, it worked. Do you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've given `gcc-4.2` as the value of the `CC` environment variable.  The configure script accepts this and tries to use it as the C compiler, but it cannot be found in `PATH`, so it fails.

Don't set the `CC` environment variable, and the configure script will try a few different alternatives to find a usable C compiler.